# Link page in html using vbscript

Tags: html, vbscript

I was trying to link a page which is in HTML using if/else conditions in vbscript but i don't know how to do that . I have tried form but i couldn't find options to attach any link with condition check statement. please help.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by following commands in vbscript-
        if  then
                CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""loction of file""")
        else
                CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""location of file""")
        end if